# How to Insert Image into SQL Azure Image Column

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

When I deploy my database to my local SQL Server 2012 machine, I run a post-deployment script that includes this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[EntityType] ON
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.[EntityType] (ID, Name, Icon)
SELECT 1, 'Client', * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\icons\client.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS tempImg
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[EntityType] OFF
GO
```

This adds a record to the EntityType table, including an image, which is added to the column *Icon* with a datatype of `Image`. When I deploy the same database to Microsoft Azure, the post-deployment script fails. On running this part of the script manually, I get the error:

> Keyword or statement option 'single_blob' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

OK, Azure SQL doesn't support SINGLE_BLOB, so how do I achieve the same thing from an SQL script for Azure? I've Googled it, and there is the odd sample hinting at how to write C# code in an application which allows a user to upload images to an Azure SQL backend, but I don't want to write a whole application with a front-end interface, I just want to add a couple of records to a table in my database!

I have to say, having advocated using Azure SQL as our database hosting solution for development, I'm rapidly beginning to regret my decision. The platform's lack of support for extended properties and now this has meant that simple database deployment has become a chore!

Comment: I am pretty sure you will need to rewrite it in .NET code (ie C#). Where do you expect the c:\ to be anyway? You can't get files onto the file system of a SQL Azure server. Probably better is to store the images in Blob storage anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and ended with a nice solution using the [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net).

1. Create new Azure Connection
2. Select `C# Program`
3. Write the script, like this:

   ```
   void Main()
   {
       var entity = MyDataTable.First(x => x.Id == 1);
       entity.Image = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\foo\\bar.png");
       SubmitChanges();
   }
   ```

Now you can hit `F5` and the database will be updated.
To use this as post-deployment script:

1. Save the script as `*.linq` file
2. Install `linqpad` on the machine, where the script should be executed, or simply copy the executables
3. Use `lprun` to run the script: `lprun myscript.linq`